# <p:pickList> not clearing after RemoveAll button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am encountering a strange problem with `<p:pickList>`. When I open a dialog having this pickList and clear all items from target list using the RemoveAll button and submit using `<p:commandButton>` the old items in the target list still appear. I have given the attribute `required=true` for the pickList.  The strange behaviour is when I submit it, a tooltip appears saying that the field is mandatory.

So if the items are clearing and `required` attribute is working fine, why are the old items reappearing? What is the solution for this?

```
<p:pickList id="selectedId" value="#{someDialog.selectedItem}"
            var="item" itemValue="#{item}" required="true"
            converter="pickListConverter" requiredMessage="#{msg.required_message}" 
            styleClass="#{component.valid ? '': 'ui-state-error'}">
        </p:pickList>
```

**EDIT:** Backing Bean - I am posting only the relevant method.
    **SomeDialog.java**

```
 private DualListModel<Item> selectedItem = new DualListModel<Item>();
 //Its getters and setters

public final void afterSave(final ParamObject pObject) {
        pObject.getRelevantData().clear();
        pObject.getRelevantData().addAll(selectedItem.getTarget());
    }
```

**ParamObject .java**

```
private List<Item> relevantData = new ArrayList<Item>();
//Setters and Getters
```

Comment: Can you write your backing bean code?

Comment: I still can't see the problem. You are trying to submit a form with a required picklist with empty target list. Obviusly, if it is required, you cannot submit it and jsf is requesting for a mandatory field. You have to put at least an item in your target list or make it not required. Old items are still appearing because the fact of the form is not being sent.

Comment: @XtremeBiker - Let me clarify you. Before I submit the form, the old items are appearing, which is fine. But when I click the RemoveAll button and submit the form, the old items are reappearing. Ideally, when I do that, it shouldn't allow me to submit the form because of the `required` attribute. It is doing that AND displaying the old items. That's puzzling me.

Comment: @XtremeBiker - I mean the old items reappear in the target list even when I clear them. Sorry, if I was confusing.

Comment: Can you post the whole form please?

Comment: this also could be if you checking in setter selectedItem, if this value is null or empty.

Answer (score 2):

As @Xtreme Biker mentioned its in your backing bean.

When first time you submit list, you set it in backing bean. Second time you open dialog, it is already there. Even if you press RemoveAll, it removes only in your browser, it doesn't work with backing bean. And your submit will not work, because you have required=true.

So you can choose one of this options:

1. remove required=true and after every submit you will need press RemoveAll and submit again empty list (its not an option).
2. after doing all required tasks in backing bean, clear someDialog.selectedItem value, update and close dialog.
3. every time you open dialog clear someDialog.selectedItem value in backing bean.

I hope it will help as I am new in here too.

Comment: It is clear that my backing bean is removing the items from the PickList. I checked it by removing `required=true` and printing the contents of the list, which was empty after RemoveAll. So in this, where does the problem lie?

Comment: put your backing bean here